# Subversion version control integration in c++ builder

Tags: svn, c++builder, c++builder-2010

Does C++ Builder has Subversion version control integration or it comes only with XE edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [PushOK](http://www.pushok.com/soft_scc_borland.php) component. I have been using this.

Answer (score 0):

Version Insight uses some of the latest Delphi languages features, latest Open Tools API and  also relies on Open Tools API fixes.
If you need Subversion support for older releases then look into [DelphiSVN](http://www.sf.net/projects/delphisvn) or the [JCL](http://jcl.delphi-jedi.org/) Version Control expert.